# Search toggle not hiding the search container

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to add a search toggle to my site header OUTSIDE the navigation menu.

I want the search toggle (green button) to display / hide the search container, but instead it seems to only focus / defocus the search container... Below is the code that I attempted to put into a snippet, but I couldn't figure out how to display the search bar here... So please refer to this image for a complete picture of the issue [search-toggle-behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYSiT.jpg). What am I missing for the search toggle to hide / show the search container? Thx so much.

```js
// Search toggle.
  jQuery( '.search-toggle' ).on( 'click.twentysixteen', function( event ) {
   var that    = jQuery( this ),
    wrapper = jQuery( '#search-container' ),
    container = that.find( 'a' );

   that.toggleClass( 'active' );
   wrapper.toggleClass( 'hide' );

   if ( that.hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
    container.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
   } else {
    container.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
   }

   if ( that.is( '.active' ) || jQuery( '.search-toggle .screen-reader-text' )[0] === event.target ) {
    wrapper.find( '.search-field' ).focus();
   }
  } );
```

```css
.search-toggle {
 background-color: #24890d;
 float: right;
 height: 48px;
 margin-right: 38px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 48px;
}

.search-toggle:hover,
.search-toggle.active {
 background-color: #41a62a;
}

.search-toggle:before {
 color: #fff;
 content: "Search";
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="search-toggle">
  <a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="search-container"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></a>
</div>
    
        
        
<div id="search-container" class="search-box-wrapper hide">
  <div class="search-box">
   <?php get_search_form(); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet will not work properly, can you add HTML instead of `php` code? also if you are using bootstrap, specify the version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using JQuery, i'd suggest that you utilize the JQuery `toggle` (`toggle` is a function that toggles between hiding and showing of the selected element). It's basically like this: if the element is hidden, `toggle` will show it, vice versa.

The `slideToggle` on the other hand is the same as `toggle` but it will have that smooth sliding effect. Once you understand how `toggle` works, just select the class or ID that you'd like to toggle between hide and show.

```js
//this will be your short jquery code. and yes, it's just a few lines

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".collapsible").click(function(){
    $(".content").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* You can ignore the rest
 and just focus on this one. 
 We start with display none 
 to hide it after loading the 
 page, and leave the rest to
 toggle function*/
.content{
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: #028A0F;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #3CB043;
}
    .content input{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>
<ul>
  <li style="float:right">
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Search</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But, this is also easy to achieve using Bootstrap.

```css
/*bootstrap has it's own navbar so this is unecessary, but just to have a consistent look with the one above, let's recycle this one*/

.collapsible {
  background-color: #028A0F;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #3CB043;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li style="float:right">
  <button type="button" class="collapsible" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Search</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
  <input class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I followed your first example and got it to work, thank you! The only wrinkle is that when the main menu toggle is also activated, this search container appears below all the main menu items. Is there a way for the slideToggle to drop down and overlap any existing content / activated navigation dropdown?